# What can I do after winning my lane?

Tags: league-of-legends

I mean, I have destroyed 2 enemy towers on my lane. I'm playing Mid-Malzahar, and I get those objectives really fast (sometimes my team mates haven't destroyed any towers yet!). Yes, I know about the danger about pushing the lane and so, but the fact is that I'm very good in killing the towers.

In the end, I don't know what I do to follow up. Its really dangerous trying beat the 3rd tower alone. I think about helping another lanes, but I'm worried that my lane will go unprotected. And an AP hero as Malzahar isn't sooo good as jungler.

What the best can I do when I won my lane so early?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several problems with answering that:

You say you don't like helping your teammates because your tower is unprotected. That means you don't think enough about lane dynamics yet. As AP mid, the way you play is basically you push the lane to the enemy tower and go do other stuff (gank other lanes, take a jungle camp, take blue, etc.). You can do that freely because the lane is pushed, the opponent can't destroy your tower since he has to push the lane back first which takes about 30 seconds to a minute until the minions are at your tower, depending on how strong you pushed the lane and how strong the opponents champion can push.
That is enough time to go to another lane and help them.
If you destroyed the first tower, you can push the lane even further back, giving you even more time to gank other lanes.

Generally speaking, once you destroyed the tower or gained the ability to insta-clear a minion wave, you should spend as little time as possible in your lane and as much time as possible ganking other lanes and then be there just in time to catch the big counterwave coming in range of your tower. In the meantime take your and sometimes even his wraith camp for some bonus farm while you go to top or bottom lane.

Another way to approach this situation with more defensive mids is to freeze the lane, that means let the lane come to you and tank it far enough away from your tower that it doesn't shoot but close enough that the enemy mid can't farm your minions. Then farm very, very slowly which denies the opponent his farm since he can't reach your minions safely and since he has no tower to back him up, it makes him extremely vulnerable to ganks which can snowball your advantage even further. However, defensive mids will rarely get into this situation in the first place.

However, the situation most likely means that the opposing team is just bad, so you could do whatever and still win. It should never occur in a match of equally strong teams of decent skill.

Comment: Great answer, with the exception of "You say you don't like helping your teammates because your tower is unprotected" I don't say it. ;)

Comment: Actually, you kinda did. "I think about helping another lanes, but I'm worried that my lane will go unprotected."

Answer (score 3):

> I think about helping another lanes, but I'm worried that my lane will go unprotected.

Your lane also has minions in it - you should clear the enemy wave before your side reaches it, then the minions will keep enemy champions/minions busy while you roam.

You should be **roaming** after you kill the first tower itself, if not before that. When you push the lane and B for buying items, sometimes you can take a detour and head bot to help with a quick gank or forcing enemy ADC or support to recall, then head to mid from there.

Also, when you have both towers down - that means you get easier access to enemy jungle, so it should be easier to coordinate with your jungler to **steal red & blue buffs**. If you can, give red buff to allies but if not - better that you grab it and deny the opponents.

Keep an eye on the other lanes too; if fights break out - you may not be able to help them in time, but if an enemy is low hp and retreating back ... you having pushed ahead could try to **intercept** them thru jungle for a kill.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push past the first tower, buy wards to help make things safe.  Defintely do not push the third tower without vision.

You can also start roaming.  Go help push another lane.  It helps to push your own lane up before you do this, of course.  Also, start trying to deny in the enemy jungle.  Take creep camps, steal buffs, etc.

If you take two towers, it's probably time for your team to group up and start really putting pressure on the enemy team.  That's a big map control advantage.  Ward their jungle and use it!